# How to put a string into mapped memory chunk?

Tags: c, linux, ftp, mmap

I'm making an FTP server on Linux and i have a function here which gets file name and size, creats a new file with the file size - the aim is to create a file on the server with data from the client (recvBuff) using mmap.

What i'm trying to do is to enter the data in recvBuff to the mapped memory (fp).

Do i need an actual write to the mapped memory?
The file is created ok but the content is as a set of NULLs (\00).

All parameters have values  - recvBuff is "hello world" and the size is not 0 and so on.

This might be relevant to file permissions VS. mmap permissions or just that i'm not doing the data copy correctly into fp.

I'm sure it's something stupid but i lost myself looking at it and debugging with printf.

Thanks

```
// recieve file from client
void put(int sockfd, char* fname, int fsize) {
int readen, nbytes,fd_src;
char recvBuff[fsize+1];
char path[256];
char cwd[1024];
char * src;

getcwd(cwd, sizeof(cwd));
sprintf(path,"/Server/%s", fname);
path[strlen(path)]='\0';
strcat(cwd,path);
strcpy(path,cwd);
printf("path:%s ,sockfd:%d , fname:%s, f_size: %d\n",path,sockfd,fname,fsize);

char* fp;
int fd;
if((fd = open(path, O_CREAT | O_RDWR | O_TRUNC, 0644)) < 0) //open new file for writing
    perror("fd"); 

lseek (fd, fsize + 1, SEEK_SET);
write (fd, "", 1);
lseek (fd, 0, SEEK_SET);


if ((fp = mmap(0, fsize, PROT_WRITE | PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, fd, 0)) == (caddr_t)-1)
    perror("mmap for output");

    if(fp== MAP_FAILED)
        printf("mmap error\n");
ftruncate(fd, fsize);
while((readen = recv(sockfd, recvBuff, sizeof recvBuff, 0))>0) {    
    src=recvBuff;
    memcpy(fp,src,readen);
    if(readen == fsize){
        munmap(fp,readen);
        close(fd);
        break;
    }
}
if(readen == -1) {
    perror("recv");
}
}
```

Comment: You need to check the documentation about what MAP_PRIVATE means.

Comment: True, as easy as that. I looked at the shared/private from a different angle. You saved me a lot of wasted time. Thanks